# PHP - Place an image over another image

Tags: php, image, gd, image-resizing

I want to place an image over another image using php. I have two images. One is a photo. And other one is a image, of fixed size, full white. We can call this as frame. So what i need is place the photo in the middle of the frame (white image) and then save it. Can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

to do this kind of work, you need to use [GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

this code work with GD library

```
       $photo_to_paste="image_to_paste.jpg";  //image 321 x 400
       $white_image="white_image.jpg"; //873 x 622 

        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($white_image);
        $condicion = GetImageSize($photo_to_paste); // image format?

        if($condicion[2] == 1) //gif
        $im2 = imagecreatefromgif("$photo_to_paste");
        if($condicion[2] == 2) //jpg
        $im2 = imagecreatefromjpeg("$photo_to_paste");
        if($condicion[2] == 3) //png
        $im2 = imagecreatefrompng("$photo_to_paste");

        imagecopy($im, $im2, (imagesx($im)/2)-(imagesx($im2)/2), (imagesy($im)/2)-(imagesy($im2)/2), 0, 0, imagesx($im2), imagesy($im2));

        imagejpeg($im,"test4.jpg",90);
        imagedestroy($im);
        imagedestroy($im2);
```

that code will output:
[image: imagr]